# Is there a difference between connect PPC to WS through ActiveSync and IP cradle?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

i build C# program on Windows-Mobile that connect to WebService through cradle

and work with ActiveSync.

the customer want me to change the program that the connection will be through IP cradle.

is it require me any code change ?

how to do it ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

It *shouldn't* require any code change.  If you can get Internet Explorer on your device to display your web service page (asmx), then your application should be able to connect to the web service as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, web requests should use connection manager which will automatically use the ip connection that is already there.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth noting here that the ActiveSync pass-through is not a full-up network bridge.  For example, ICMP packets don't pass through it.  For a Web Service call using port 80 HTTP commands, however, you should be fine.